# Customize Civi's UI on WordPress?

Tags: ui

Is there a way to customize the actual UI of Civi?

I'm sorry, but it's the ugliest thing I've seen in *years*.

I understand if not, but... it's gross.

Using WordPress (current version), multisite network.

Answer (score 1):

This alternate theme for wordpress is available: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/haystacktheme

You can also add your own css by writing a little extension that adds your own css file: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/resources/#css-stylesheets

Comment: God bless you. I'll look into both.

Answer (score 1):

The [CiviCRM Admin Utilities](https://wordpress.org/plugins/civicrm-admin-utilities/) plugin offers an alternative theme for CiviCRM (on which the "Haystack Theme" Extension is based) that makes it look like a native WordPress plugin. FWIW it also offers many other useful options - particularly if you're on WordPress Multisite.